# ModuleNotFound: No module name pyaudio

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio, raspberry-pi4

I am not able to install pyaudio in raspberry pi..

Tried the command
`sudo apt install python3-pyaudio`

it says python3-pyaudio is already installed.. but when i try to import pyaudio. **ModuleNotFound** error is thrown...

Comment: Why are you using `apt` to install?  `pip` is the usual way to do that.

Comment: Please show us the output of this command `dpkg -L python3-pyaudio` and also of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyAudio has dependencies that need to be installed. Make sure you have the necessary libraries. Such as :

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```

Also, instead of using the package manager, you can try installing PyAudio using pip.

```
pip3 install pyaudio
```